# Fetch all nearby cellular carriers and their signal strength on iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone

Do we have some api/class that help me fetch list of all cellular carriers nearby me with their respective strengths, like we choose cellular network manually, it lists all network providers.
I want to implement it in my upcoming project, just fetching all nearby cellular network providers for iOS app.

Comment: We need a few more details than that.  Are you writing a native app or cross-platform?  What libraries/frameworks are you already using?  What have you already tried?

Comment: I am writing a native app for iphone/ipad

Comment: Did you solve your issue? I am also interested in this.